# How to update Contact Country after Lead is converted to Contact?

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

I need to populate Contact Country field with Account's Country value when Lead is converted to Contact and Country field on Lead record is blank. We cannot do it on Before Insert trigger since that setting(Require Validation for Converted Leads) on Lead is turned off. Neither on After Insert Apex Trigger nor using Process Builder. Tried both already. So what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: are you saying that `Require Validation for Converted Leads` in Lead Settings is unchecked?

Comment: Yes that's right. So BeforeTriggers aren't triggering.

Comment: Are you amenable to using Flow in lieu of Process Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `Require Validation for Converted Lead` is unchecked, DML events on the converted objects (Account, Contact, Opportunity) do not initiate triggers or other automation.

However, there will be a DML event on the Lead itself (to set `IsConverted = true` and also set the Ids of the converted Account, Contact, and Opportunity.

So, using either an after update trigger or after save Flow on Leads where `IsConverted=true`, you can query for the converted Account and Contact and set the Contact's Country per the converted Account.

Comment: Thank you!! I used After Trigger on Lead object and it almost worked. Only issue is, if there is any Contact validation error, it's stopping Trigger execution. Though we have disabled the setting, it's still throwing validation error!! Any advise?

Comment: You would need to amend the Contact VR to allow your update to occur; VRs run at the database level and are designed to prevent invalid data from being saved. You can not bypass VRs; you can only change the VR's conditions

Comment: Sure I will find a workaround for that, thank you very much again!!